# Ajax.ActionLink and jquery execution in PartialView after Ajax request

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I load some PartialView in page as response to Ajax form post. This partial contains two Ajax.ActionLink by self. After response load ActionLinks doesn't work properly - it send request to server but doesn't updates UpdateTarget with returned content.
Seems like jquery-ui provided widgets (like draggable) can't bind to elements in way like this (code placed in partial view):

```
$(function(){ $('#target').draggable();});
```

I would appreciate for any solutions.

PS> ActionLinks starts work after target id correction, but jquery ui steel don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by add named function in PartialView and call it in OnSuccess for Ajax.BeginForm. As I discover document.ready fires for ajax-loaded content before page is really updated.

Comment: someElement.load() might work better than document.ready().  [load] (http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)  OnSuccess is a perfect place, but some times I like to keep my js on the partial view it is associated with so I don't forget it when using it in other places.

Answer (score 1):

seems #target is not avilable when your code is binding the handler..

try using `live()`, or `delegate()`, or `.on()`

Comment: I'm tried live(), but looks like "ready" can't be captured for div. What event to use in this case?

Comment: try debbgging by placing alerts in document ready of partial..if it works then try $('#target') there

Comment: as I know Visual Studio debugger for MVC can't attach to JavaScript, and in-browser debugger can't debug scripts in dynamically loaded Partial View.